# USB and ETH drop

Tags: usb

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest buster. Had an event where the USB & ETH (no wifi on this one) dropped at the same time.  No idea why.
Of course, since I don't have to automount enabled, the ext4 FS on the USB didn't automatically remount.

```
No fs errors in the logs
vcgencmd get_throttled = 0x0
uptime = 53 days
No undervoltages in the system logs
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

```
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:35 2020] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583, bcdDevice= 1.00
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb 2-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxx
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:36 2020] bcmgenet fd580000.genet eth0: Link is Down
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 242614272 512-byte logical blocks: (124 GB/116 GiB)
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020]  sda: sda1
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:37 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[Wed Jan  8 11:08:39 2020] bcmgenet fd580000.genet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
```

Comment: Is PSU correct type?

Comment: Scan the system logs for `Under-voltage detected!` to confirm the premise that it is a power issue.

Comment: Using the correct / original USB C psu.  No under voltages.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to diagnose this if the condition is not repeatable. A USB disconnect happens every time the driver doesn't receive something it expected from the device, which can be due to a bug in the driver, a bug in the device, or a transient event like a power surge / drop / EM interference. Getting a disconnect on a NIC at the same time suggests the later.

Not having "under-voltage" in the kernel logs excludes power supply incompatibility (which manifests as repeated events of low voltage on 5V line), but it doesn't mean the power was actually OK the whole time. For one, it could have been an over-voltage, or an under-voltage on a line that isn't monitored.